# CSV reader putting /n after each row

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I have generated a CSV file from excel.
I am trying to read this CSV file using python CSV. However after each row I get /n. How to remove this /n.

Here is my code:

```
with open('/users/ps/downloads/test.csv','rU') as csvfile
      spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile,dialect=csv.excel_tab)
      a = [] 
      for row in csvfile:
        a.append(row)
 print a
```

I get result like this:

```
['HEADER\n', 'a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', 'd\n', 'e']
```

I want to have results like this:

```
['HEADER', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try a replace

```
a.replace('\n','')
```

edit:

working verison- `a.append(row.replace('\n',''))`

Comment: It worked but not before print, in for loop `a.append(row.replace('\n',''))`
Thanks

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, glad to help out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip)

```
x = ['HEADER\n', 'a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', 'd\n', 'e']

In [6]: def f(word):
   ...:     return word.strip()
   ...:

In [7]: map(f, x)
Out[7]: ['HEADER', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

In [8]:
```